# xml parse and return list of objects

Tags: xml, scala

In scala, is there a simple way to get all elements of an XML doc represented as a list?

My code:

```
object HelloWorld {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val res="76561193756669631"
    val url=("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXYYYZZZ&steamids="+res+"&format=xml")
    val str = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url.toString,"utf-8").mkString
    val x=xml.XML.loadString(str)
    var r=(x\\"steamid").mkString
    r=r.replaceAll("""<[a-zA-Z0-9/]*?>""","")
    println(r)

}}
```

retrieves the xml:

```
<response>
<players>
<player>
<steamid>76561193756669631</steamid>
<communityvisibilitystate>3</communityvisibilitystate>
<personaname>*******je01</personaname>
<lastlogoff>1320236285</lastlogoff>
<profileurl>
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561193756669631/
</profileurl>
<avatar>
https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg
</avatar>
<avatarmedium>
https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg
</avatarmedium>
<avatarfull>
https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg
</avatarfull>
<personastate>0</personastate>
<primaryclanid>103582791429521408</primaryclanid>
<timecreated>1320224696</timecreated>
<personastateflags>0</personastateflags>
</player>
</players>
</response>
```

and outputs the steamid because I hardcoded it in. Is there a way to oputput a list of all the elements and their values?

My goal:

```
steamid: 76561193756669631
communityvisibilitystate: 3
personaname: *******je01
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you have to do to get those elements:

```
  import scala.xml._
  val x = <response>
    <players>
      <player>
        <steamid>76561193756669631</steamid>
        <communityvisibilitystate>3</communityvisibilitystate>
        <personaname>*******je01</personaname>
        <lastlogoff>1320236285</lastlogoff>
        <profileurl>
          http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561193756669631/
        </profileurl>
        <avatar>
          https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg
        </avatar>
        <avatarmedium>
          https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg
        </avatarmedium>
        <avatarfull>
          https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg
        </avatarfull>
        <personastate>0</personastate>
        <primaryclanid>103582791429521408</primaryclanid>
        <timecreated>1320224696</timecreated>
        <personastateflags>0</personastateflags>
      </player>
    </players>
  </response>

  val allNodes = x \\ "response" \\ "players" \\ "player"  flatMap(_.child)
  allNodes.foreach(n => println(s"label: ${n.label} -> text: ${n.text}"))
```

first find the all players then get the attributes you need. And you will get the following(some doesn't have any text):

```
label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: steamid -> text: 76561193756669631
label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: communityvisibilitystate -> text: 3
label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: personaname -> text: *******je01
label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: lastlogoff -> text: 1320236285
label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: profileurl -> text: 
          http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561193756669631/

label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: avatar -> text: 
          https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg

label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: avatarmedium -> text: 
          https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg

label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: avatarfull -> text: 
          https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg

label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: personastate -> text: 0
label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: primaryclanid -> text: 103582791429521408
label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: timecreated -> text: 1320224696
label: #PCDATA -> text: 

label: personastateflags -> text: 0
label: #PCDATA -> text:
```

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted, but I cant figure out where the `label: #PCDATA -> text:` is coming from. When I view the source I dont see it at all. Is it hidden in the XML somehow? If so, can I just filter it out?

Comment: here: `println(s"label: ${n.label} -> text: ${n.text}")` it's sugar for strings in Scala. allNodes is NodeSeq which you can iterate over it

Comment: The `#PCDATA` you see is the text between a close tag and a open tag. In the example there are only white characters (spaces and new lines), but if you put some text between let's say `</steamid>` and `<communityvisibilitystate>`, you will see it as `#PCDATA` in the output. You can filter it out with this: `x \\ "response" \\ "players" \\ "player"  flatMap(_.child) filter(!_.isAtom)`